# When click on button the data is'nt saving in the database? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to save some information from a page into the database, I think that my used code is true, but I don't know why it not saved to access database?

Database name--> `Database1`

Table Name --> `Table1`

Fields Name --> `Name,Email,Mobile,Laptop,WhatYouNeedFromUs,WhereAreYouFrom`

Type-->`Text`

The connection is fine just the data not inserted and saved into database I don't know why!!

ContactUs.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactUs.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContactUs" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" style="width:80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:50px; background-color:#fff" >
        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server" Width="50%" Text="Name " HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="black" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="1px"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        Width="99%" MaxLength="20" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell3" runat="server" Width="50%" Text="Email " HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="black" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell4" runat="server" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="1px"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        Width="99%" MaxLength="20" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow3" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell5" runat="server" Width="50%" Text="Mobile Phone " HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="black" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell6" runat="server" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="1px"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        Width="99%" MaxLength="20" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow4" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server"  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" HorizontalAlign="Right">Which Laptop You Want?</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" runat="server"  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" ColumnSpan="2"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large">
        <asp:ListItem>Hp</asp:ListItem>


<asp:ListItem>Samsung</asp:ListItem>


<asp:ListItem>Sony</asp:ListItem>


<asp:ListItem>Lenovo</asp:ListItem>


</asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow5" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell9" runat="server" Width="50%" Text="What you need from us?" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="black" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" runat="server" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="1px"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" placeholder="Enter what you want" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        Width="99%" MaxLength="200" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow6" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell11" runat="server" Width="50%" Text="Where Are You From? " HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="black" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell12" runat="server" BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="1px"><asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Rows="1" Width="99%">
        <asp:ListItem>Kurdistan</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem>Iraq</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem>Italy</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem>Netherlands</asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>

</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>


        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow7" runat="server" >
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="Larger"><asp:Button ID="Button1"  style="margin-top:20px;" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="Red" Text="Submit" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>


    </asp:Table>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br />
</asp:Content>
```

C# code:
ContaceUs.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sevar\Documents\Database1.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "Insert into Table1 (Name,Email,Mobile,Laptop,WhatYouNeedFromUs,WhereAreYouFrom) Values('" + TextBox1 + "','" + TextBox2 + "','" + TextBox3 + "','" + RadioButtonList1 + "','" + TextBox4 + "','" + ListBox1 + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Parameters and not use direct user inputs for SQL.... also may you don't want to save your textbox, I think you want to save your textbox.Text (the same for RadioButtonList and ListBox, you won't save the control, you want to save (some) underlying values...

Comment: I'm new in C# and I'm just trying to save the data into the database.. I had change the `textbox` --> `textbox.Text` , still the data isn't saving! @CyrilIselin

Comment: It's not saving it's not a question, and also not an error, please show us some effort and read my text again, you can't save controls into the database, you have to save some control values into your database. ( a control my contains: width, height, font, color, ....)

Comment: But why you think that this implementation will save controls not control values? @CyrilIselin

Comment: What type have TextBox1 and RadioButtonList1 and ListBox1 ?

Comment: I think all of them are Text? aren't they?

Comment: No, TextBox is of type TextBox, TextBox.Text is of type string. RadioButtonList is of type RadioButtonList...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the way to solve this. I'll try then I'll answer you :). Thank you. @CyrilIselin